# Can't connect to my Amazon EC2 instance either via SSH or via browser

Tags: amazon-ec2

So I just launched my ec2 instance : t2.micro with Ubuntu 14.04 OS. The security group has settings enabled for letting in inbound traffic from SSH ( port 22 ) and HTTP ( port 80 ). But when I try to reach the server from the browser via its public dns : ec2-52-74-136-74.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com it says connection refused. And if I try to ssh it says : Permission denied (publickey).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That machine is up and responding on 22. Have you added your SSH key into your agent?

```
ssh-add -l
```

should show it listed. Don't forget to ssh as ubuntu@

Comment: So stupid of me. Yes the pem file was not in the agents list. Thankyou.

Comment: So I used to connect with my earlier ec2 instance but I had configured the ssh key in the ~/.ssh/config file instead of adding it as an agent via `ssh-add`. But that config was for my old machine's IP, and therefore wasn't working for my new ec2 credentials.